# Determining Integrability of Family of Functions

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

> For $n = 1, 2, 3, \dots$ and $\alpha > 0$ define for $x \in \mathbb{R}$:
> $$g_{n,\alpha}(x) = e^{-\alpha^n(x-n)^2}\cos^2(x-n),$$
> and let
> $$f_\alpha(x) = \sup_{n \geq 1}g_{n, \alpha}(x).$$
> For which values of $\alpha$ is $f_\alpha \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R})$?

**My attempt:**

First note when $x < 0$ then $g_{n,a}(x) \leq e^{-\alpha x^2} \leq e^{-x^2} \implies f_\alpha(x) \leq e^{-x^2}$ which is integrable. Hence, to determine whether $f_\alpha$ is integrable, it is sufficient to only determine whether $f_\alpha$ is integrable on $x > 0$.

Consider when $\alpha = 1$. Then $g_{n,1} = e^{-(x-n)^2}\cos^2(x-n)$. For all $x > 0$, there exists a $n' \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\vert x - n '\vert < 1$. So we have that $f_1(x) \geq g_{n',1}(x) \geq e^{-1}\cos^2(1)$ for $x > 0$. This shows that $f_1$ is not integrable.
For $0 < \alpha < 1$, we have that $g_{n, \alpha} \geq g_{n,1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence it follows that $f_\alpha \geq f_1$ and thus $f_\alpha$ is also not integrable for $0 < \alpha < 1$.

For $\alpha > 1$, I am not sure what to do. My feeling is that $f_\alpha$ should be integrable in this case. However, I am not sure how to get an integrable upper bound for $f_\alpha(x)$ for $x > 0$.